# How can I simulate multiple monitors with only one screen and alternate between them?

Tags: multiple-monitors, streaming

I've searched thoroughly through superuser and I found people with similar problems, but not quite the one I have and the solutions I found don't apply to me.

Here's the scenario: I have one monitor and I'm trying to stream a game that doesn't work well with window capture or game capture, so my only option is to stream my whole screen. However, I'd like to be able to use the streaming software without it appearing on stream. What I'm thinking is:

If I have 2 virtual monitors and I can alternate between them (say, with a keyboard shortcut), it would be as simple as having the game on one monitor and the streaming software on the other.
Basically I want to be able to alternate between my screen (which currently is essentially Monitor 1) showing Monitor 1 or Monitor 2, and then have the streaming software capture only Monitor 1.

The other solutions I found here don't apply because those users either 1. need to see all monitors at the same time on their screen or 2. don't need the content of Monitor 2 not to appear in Monitor 1 (so they can use VNC, for example)

Comment: The solution that occurs to me right off is not switching-via-keystroke, but to use two different inputs (e.g., one DVI and one HDMI) to the same monitor, and switching between them via the hardware control on the monitor to select which input to use.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin,that would be interesting, but unfortunately my monitor only has one input (VGA).